# Resource List Display on Gantt Chart

Tags: ms-project

Apologies upfront, complete novice to MS Project.  I've got a project where I am trying to present the resources I will need for each task.  When I allocate resources to the task and display them on the Gantt chart, each item is separated by a comma and placed in the same row.  This is also cut off after so many resources are in the view.

[image]

Current View

Is there any way to convert this into a bulleted list underneath the bar? Something like this terrible MS Paint edit.

[image]

How I'd like it to look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to convert this into a bulleted list underneath the bar?

No, this is not possible. You *can* switch the view from ***Gantt Chart*** to ***Task Usage*** and see something like this:

[image: Task Usage View]

**Warning**: entering data while in the Task Usage View is dangerous and should be avoided unless you really know what you are doing.

There are some 3rd party tools that can help give you different views of your tasks and resources assigned to them but they aren't free.